# Databricks - How to join a table with IDs contained in a column of type struct<array<string>>

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

I currently have JSON file from which I'm able to dump it's data into a temporary view  via. following Python (PySpark) logic:

```
 departMentData = spark \
                .read \
                .option("multiLine", True) \
                .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE") \
                .json("C:\\Test\data.json") \
                .createOrReplaceTempView("vw_TestView")
```

This temporary view has the data of departments and list of employees within that department in an array. One employee can be a part of multiple departments.

Following is this view's datatypes:

- DeptID: string
- DeptName: string
- EmployeeIDs: array<string.>

and the table data for **vw_TestView** is as follows

| DeptID | DeptName | EmployeeIDs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D01 | dev | ["U1234", "U6789"] |
| D02 | qa | ["U1234", "U2345"] |

and another table **Employees** has details of all these employees as follows:

| EmpID | EmpName |
| --- | --- |
| U1234 | jon |
| U6789 | smith |
| U2345 | natasha |

I need the final output for a new table to be as follows:

| DeptID | DeptName | EmployeeIDs | EmployeeNames |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D01 | dev | ["U1234", "U6789"] | ["jon", "smith"] |
| D02 | qa | ["U1234", "U2345"] | ["jon", "natasha"] |

How can such joins be performed in either Databricks SQL or via PySPark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following which uses `explode` to split the list of Employee Ids into different rows before joining them and using `collect_list` to aggregate the entries into a list.

Using spark sql:

**NB.** *Ensure `Employees` is available as a table/view eg `EmployeeData.createOrReplaceTempView("Employees")`*

```sql
WITH dept_employees AS (
    SELECT
        DeptId,
        DeptName,
        explode(EmployeeIDs)
    FROM
        vw_TestView
)
SELECT
    d.DeptId,
    d.DeptName,
    collect_list(e.EmpID) as EmployeeIDs,
    collect_list(e.EmpName) as EmployeeNames
FROM
    dept_employees d
INNER JOIN
    Employees e ON d.col=e.EmpID
GROUP BY
    d.Deptid,
    d.DeptName
```

or using pyspark api:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

output_df = (
    departMentData.select(
        F.col("DeptId"),
        F.col("DeptName"),
        F.explode("EmployeeIDs")
    )
    .alias("d")
    .join(
        EmployeeData.alias("e"),
        F.col("d.col")==F.col("e.EmpID"),
        "inner"
    )
    .groupBy("d.DeptId","d.DeptName")
    .agg(
        F.collect_list("e.EmpID").alias("EmployeeIDs"),
        F.collect_list("e.EmpName").alias("EmployeeNames")
    )
)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Both of these approaches work.

Comment: How performant is this compared to a regular join on flat data?